# How to make thumbnails from pictures?

Tags: windows-10

If you're familiar with MPC media player you'd probably know that there is an option to make thumbnails for your videos.

Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/geAoPDL

So I'm looking for something that can do the same but for pictures. For example, turning 1000 pictures into one big thumbnail (composed of columns and rows just like in the screenshot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any graphics utility can make thumbnails of 1000 images as a batch process

For example, imagemagick, irfanview and many others.

```
mogrify -format gif -path thumbs -thumbnail 100x100 *.jpg  
montage *.gif -geometry +2+2 montage.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to generate a [contact print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_print) from a group of photographs.

[Snap2Img](https://www.rlvision.com/snap2img/about.php) is free software that will do just that.

> Snap2IMG generates contact sheets (also known as thumbnail sheets or
> image index) for folders on your hard drive. The result is a larger
> image containing thumnails showing all the images in the folder. It
> can process a single folder or a complete folder structure,
> automatically generating a sheet for each subfolder. A large number of
> options allows you to style the sheets to your own liking.